# iOS Utility methods for UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, gui, uikit, thundercats

Lately, I've been part of a team working on a utility library for iOS called Thundercats ([on Github](https://github.com/metova/ThunderCats)).  We're about to start working on some changes and upgrades in preparation for a 2.0 release, so we figured it might be a good time to get some of our code publicly reviewed.

The library is written in Objective-C and is set up to work with Cocoapods, but we want to make sure we the library works well from iOS 6.0 and up and with both Swift and Objective-C.

This code is from the `UIView` extension.  It provides an easy means of doing some common recursive searching.

#### [UIView+TCAdditions.h](https://github.com/metova/ThunderCats/blob/master/Categories/UIView%2BTCAdditions.h)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, TCSearchStrategy) {
    TCSearchStrategyBreadthFirst,
    TCSearchStrategyDepthFirst
};

@interface UIView (TCAdditions)

/**
 *  Calls resignFirstResponder on this view or its subviews (1 level down) if the view is the first responder.
 */
- (void)tc_findAndResignFirstResponder;

/**
 *  Returns a flattened subview hierarchy. All subviews within this view's subview hierarchy are returned.
 *
 *  @return An array of all the view's subviews in its subview hierarchy.
 */
- (NSArray *)tc_getAllSubviewsRecursively;

/**
 *  Returns the first subview it encounters that satisfies the condition block. This method uses a breadth first search strategy.
 *
 *  @param conditionBlock The block to apply to each subview.
 *
 *  @return The first subview encountered that satisfies the condition block.
 */
- (UIView *)tc_subviewThatSatisfiesBlock:(BOOL (^)(UIView *))conditionBlock;

/**
 *  Returns the first subview it encounters that satisfies the condition block. This method can perform a breadth first search strategy or a depth first search strategy.
 *
 *  @param searchStrategy The search strategy to use.
 *  @param conditionBlock The block to apply to each subview.
 *
 *  @return The first subview encountered that satisfies the condition block.
 */
- (UIView *)tc_findSubviewUsingSearchStrategy:(TCSearchStrategy)searchStrategy
                           thatSatisfiesBlock:(BOOL (^)(UIView *view))conditionBlock;

@end
```

#### [UIView+TCAdditions.m](https://github.com/metova/ThunderCats/blob/master/Categories/UIView%2BTCAdditions.m)

```
#import "UIView+TCAdditions.h"

@implementation UIView (TCAdditions)

- (void)tc_findAndResignFirstResponder
{
    if ([self isFirstResponder])
    {
        [self resignFirstResponder];
        return;
    }

    for (UIView *subview in [self subviews])
    {
        if ([subview isFirstResponder])
        {
            [subview resignFirstResponder];
            return;
        }
    }
}


- (NSArray *)tc_getAllSubviewsRecursively
{
    NSMutableArray *subviews = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews)
    {
        [subviews addObject:subview];
        [subviews addObjectsFromArray:[subview tc_getAllSubviewsRecursively]];
    }

    return subviews;
}


- (UIView *)tc_subviewThatSatisfiesBlock:(BOOL (^)(UIView *))conditionBlock
{
    return [self tc_findSubviewUsingSearchStrategy:TCSearchStrategyBreadthFirst
                                thatSatisfiesBlock:conditionBlock];
}


- (UIView *)tc_findSubviewUsingSearchStrategy:(TCSearchStrategy)searchStrategy
                           thatSatisfiesBlock:(BOOL (^)(UIView *))conditionBlock
{
    switch (searchStrategy)
    {
        case TCSearchStrategyBreadthFirst:
            return [self tc_breadthFirstSubviewThatSatisfiesBlock:conditionBlock];

        case TCSearchStrategyDepthFirst:
            return [self tc_depthFirstSubviewThatSatisfiesBlock:conditionBlock];
    }
}


- (UIView *)tc_depthFirstSubviewThatSatisfiesBlock:(BOOL (^)(UIView *))conditionBlock
{
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews)
    {
        if (conditionBlock(subview))
        {
            return subview;
        }
        else
        {
            UIView *view = [subview tc_depthFirstSubviewThatSatisfiesBlock:conditionBlock];

            if (view)
            {
                return view;
            }
        }
    }

    return nil;
}


- (UIView *)tc_breadthFirstSubviewThatSatisfiesBlock:(BOOL (^)(UIView *))conditionBlock
{
    NSMutableArray *nextViewsToCheck = [self.subviews mutableCopy];

    NSInteger i = 0;
    while (i < nextViewsToCheck.count)
    {
        UIView *view = nextViewsToCheck[i];
        if (conditionBlock(view))
        {
            return view;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
            [nextViewsToCheck addObjectsFromArray:view.subviews];
        }
    }

    return nil;
}


@end
```

Any comments improving the readability, efficiency, or just making the code more idiomatic Objective-C would all be more than welcome.

Answer (score 7):

I have only some small suggestions. The

```
- (NSArray *)tc_getAllSubviewsRecursively
```

method creates a (temporary) mutable array for each subview in the
hierarchy. It might be more effective to create only a single array
and passing this array around to *append* subviews recursively:

```
- (NSArray *)tc_getAllSubviewsRecursively {
    NSMutableArray *subviews = [NSMutableArray new];
    [self tc_addSubviewsRecursivelyTo:subviews];
    return subviews;
}

// Private helper method:
- (void)tc_addSubviewsRecursivelyTo:(NSMutableArray *)subviews {
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        [subviews addObject:subview];
        [subview tc_addSubviewsRecursivelyTo:subviews];
    }
}
```

---

If you decide to use Xcode 7 and the latest OS X SDK at some point
then you can use the Objective-C "Lightweight Generics" to specify
that the returned array contains `UIView` objects:

```
- (NSArray<UIView *> *)tc_getAllSubviewsRecursively;
```

so that this causes a compiler warning:

```
NSString *foo = [self.view tc_getAllSubviewsRecursively][0];
// Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSString *' with an expression of type 'UIView *'
```

---

The

```
- (void)tc_findAndResignFirstResponder;
```

method searches only one level deep for the first responder. You could
implement it using the recursive search as

```
- (void)tc_findAndResignFirstResponder {
    if ([self isFirstResponder]) {
        [self resignFirstResponder];
        return;
    }

    UIView *subview = [self tc_subviewThatSatisfiesBlock:^BOOL(UIView *view) {
        return [view isFirstResponder];
    }];
    [subview resignFirstResponder];
}
```

where the final `[subview resignFirstResponder]` does nothing if
the search return `nil`.

This would become even more simpler if you change the search methods
to include the receiver itself in the search instead of starting
the search at its subviews.

---

In both `tc_depthFirstSubviewThatSatisfiesBlock:` and
`tc_breadthFirstSubviewThatSatisfiesBlock` the `else` is not necessary
because the method *returns* in the `if` case. This saves one
indentation level:

```
- (UIView *)tc_depthFirstSubviewThatSatisfiesBlock:(BOOL (^)(UIView *))conditionBlock
{
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        if (conditionBlock(subview)) {
            return subview;
        }
        UIView *view = [subview tc_depthFirstSubviewThatSatisfiesBlock:conditionBlock];
        if (view) {
            return view;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: The framework automatically dispatches nil-targeted action methods to the first responder, so an alternative to rummaging around the view hierarchy would be to simply send the following message: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];`

Answer (score 2):

I have three stylistic suggestions.

Regarding your method names: `...SubviewSatisfyingCondition:` sounds more Cocoa to my ears than your wording; especially the pronoun "That" seems unusual/superfluous. Also, [methods beginning with "get" should return values indirectly](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-1004202-BCIGGFCC); thus `tc_getAllSubviewsRecursively` should just be `tc_allSubviews` (I'm not sure it's important to the caller that the method is recursive).

Second, it's hard to see what calling `tc_depthFirstSubviewThatSatisfiesBlock:` would mean with a `nil` Block, but right now that will cause a crash. I'd suggest that you make the requirement explicit and do at least one of:

- Document that the Block must not be `nil`
- Assert in the method that the Block is not `nil`

With the latter option, if for some reason a user of your library thinks that it makes sense to pass a `nil` Block, they will have an easier time figuring out what's going on if execution dies with a useful error message rather than an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

A (probably undesirable) alternative would be to check for a `nil` Block and simply return the first subview. Regardless, something should be done about the `nil` case.

The third -- fairly minor -- point is that I would probably prefer, as a user of your library, to see a `typedef BOOL (^TCSubviewPredicate)(UIView *);` (or whatever name you like) in the header, and `TCSubviewPredicate` as the argument type for those search methods. Xcode will expand the type when I make the method call, but should I need to keep one of these Blocks around in a variable, its purpose is more explicit (and it's easier to type out).